# Knockout.js - Add quantity option for each item in a foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observable array "products" that includes products objects and the products objects are printed with the `foreach` binding. What I want is to insert an input box next to each product row, together with an add to cart button so the user can select quantity for each product and all this information to be added to the cart. How can I achieve this ?

Please help, I'm a newbie in knockout.js. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PGh6y/1/

Comment: There are multiple examples : http://knockoutjs.com/examples/betterList.html http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html  on the [Knockout homepage](http://knockoutjs.com/index.html) which showing how this can be done. Have you checked any of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `quantity` [observable property](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) to your Product object:

```
var Product = function (id, name, price)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = ko.observable(1);   
};
```

Then you need to use the [`value` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) on your input to be able to edit the `quantity`:

```
<input id="quantity" type="number" min="1" data-bind="value: quantity" />
```

Finally in your `addToCart` [you can get the current item as the first parameter](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-1-passing-a-current-item-as-a-parameter-to-your-handler-function) of the method so you just need to create a new `orderedItem` and push into your `orderedItems` collections:

```
self.addToCart = function (product) {
  self.orderedItems.push(
   new orderedItem(product.id, product.name, product.price, product.quantity()));
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZTLv/).

Note: I've also fixed the `removeFromCart` and the wrong property names in the second table.